# ErrorException Undefined variable in Laravel

Tags: laravel-7

I am new PHP.I am starting Laravel. Please kindly help. I cannot find why ErrorException Undefined variable.

**ProductController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Models\Product;
use DB;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $products = DB::table('products')->get();
        return view('product.index',compact('products'));
    }
}
```

This my **View**

```
 <tr>
      @foreach($products as $pro)
        <td>{{ $pro->product_name }}</td>
        <td>000012</td>
        <td>It is the product of France.</td>
        <td>image.png</td>
        <td>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Details</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
      @endforeach  
      </tr>
```

Comment: What's undefined?

Comment: <td>{{ $pro->product_name }}</td> this point

Comment: What is the output of `dd($products);`

Comment: @sta $products is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $products }} with {{ $products ?? '' }}